# SET mysql variable with list of mails

Tags: mysql

I need to define a list of variables to use in multiple MySQL queries.

The variable will be a list of mails. I have tried to define it in different ways but it always gives me error in the construction.

```
SET @listamails='mail1@gmail.com,mail2@gmail.com';

Select * from user WHERE mail IN (@listamails);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You need prepared  statement for this

Comment: Thank you. I had read that thread but I did not see that it solved my problem. Now I have seen it clear.

My final code:
SET @listamails='mail1@gmail.com,mail2@gmail.com';
Select * from user WHERE FIND_IN_SET(email, @listamails);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass in a list to `IN` using a single variable.  The simplest solution in MySQL is `find_in_set()`:

```
Select u.*
from user u
where find_in_set(mail, @listamails) > 0;
```

However, this cannot take advantage of an index.  For that, you might want to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SET @listamails='mail1@gmail.com','mail2@gmail.com';

Select * from user WHERE mail IN (@listamails);
```